# jQuery - Find dynamically created element without events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dynamically-generated

Tho this question has been asked before, and the answer is this:

```
$('#container').on('click','#dynamicElement', function(){ /* the code */ });
```

The code above will find the `#dynamicElement` when its being clicked on.
But what if there is no click, nor any other event?

Suppose the following scenario:

```
$.ajax(
    url:'file.php',
    data: {'param':'value'},
    success: function(response){
         /*
         how would I get #dynamicElement if it was not click on?
         the element had no event fired at all, nor had any of its parennt
         containers.

          Now what?
         */
    }
);
```

Comment: It looks like you want to get the element inside the success callback by using the normal jquery selector `$('#dynamicElement')`

Comment: I suppose it IS as easy as `$('#dynamicElement')`, i had always avoided doing that, as i though i knew it would not ever work

Answer (score 4):

If your new element is being added to the page inside the `success` callback, 
at that point you can call `$('#dynamicElement')`

Using `$('#dynamicElement')` anywhere outside of the callback would not return the element since it had not been added to the DOM yet.

Comment: Thanks. Care to explain why this is so?

Comment: I am assuming that `#dynamicElement` is being added to the page on the success function.  It basically comes down to that fact that you need to query for the element once it exists on the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

How event binding works is as long as that element is in the DOM itself, you can access it by writing a selector like the following:

```
$('#dynamicElement')
```

The reason you need event delegation is when you dynamically create the elements *after* you bound the event. Then, when the event is fired, it looks through all the children of the element you bound it to to find if there are any elements matching your selector.

However, if you know that the element has already been appended to the DOM, you can bind it directly without event delegation, and access it through finding it by ID.

If it hasn't yet, there is no way for you to manipulate it as it doesn't exist yet.