# Cannot find elements that are dynamically created by Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

In my jsp page, I use a Ajax call to insert a table body to the existing table. I have another jquery function which find the max value in certain rows in the table and change the background color. However, it seems that jquery cannot find the elements that are dynamically created by Ajax.

Ajax call:

```
function getRelTable(type) {
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        dataType : "html",
        cache : false,
        url : _ctx + "/monitor/get_table.do",
        data : {
            "type" : type,
        },
        success : function(content) {
            //var t_body = $(content);
            $("#table_body").html(content);
            findMax();
        },
        error : function() {
            ui.msg('信息加载错误', 0);
        }
    }); 
}
```

And the content in this Ajax is from a jsp page:

```
<c:forEach var="nodeRel" items="${nodeRelInfo}" varStatus="stc">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${stc.first}">

                <tr>
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;"
                        rowspan="3">${stc.count}</td>
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;"
                        valign="middle" align="center" rowspan="3">${nodeRel.fromNodeName}
                        --> ${nodeRel.toNodeName}</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <c:forEach var="x" begin="0" end="23" step="1">
                        <td>${x}</td>
                    </c:forEach>
                </tr>
                <tr class="value_row">
                    <td>${nodeRel.fromNodeName}发送</td>
                    <c:forEach var="node" items="${nodeRel.sendFinalList}">
                        <td class="value_cell" value="${node}"><c:choose>
                                <c:when test="${empty node}">
                                    -
                                </c:when>
                                <c:otherwise>
                                    ${node}
                                </c:otherwise>
                            </c:choose></td>
                    </c:forEach>

                </tr>
                <tr class="value_row">
                    <td>${nodeRel.toNodeName}发送</td>
                    <c:forEach var="node" items="${nodeRel.recvFinalList}">
                        <td class="value_cell" value="${node}"><c:choose>
                                <c:when test="${empty node}">
                                    -
                                </c:when>
                                <c:otherwise>
                                    ${node}
                                </c:otherwise>
                            </c:choose></td>
                    </c:forEach>
                </tr>

            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <tr class="value_row">
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;"
                        rowspan="2">${stc.count}</td>
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;"
                        valign="middle" align="center" rowspan="2">${nodeRel.fromNodeName}
                        --> ${nodeRel.toNodeName}</td>
                    <td>${nodeRel.fromNodeName}发送</td>
                    <%-- <c:forEach var="node" items="${nodeRel.sendFinalList}">
                        <td class="value_cell" value="${node}"><c:choose>
                                <c:when test="${empty node}">
                                    -
                                </c:when>
                                <c:otherwise>
                                    ${node}
                                </c:otherwise>
                            </c:choose></td>

                    </c:forEach> --%>
                    <c:forEach var="x" begin="0" end="23" step="1"> 
                            <td value="${x}">${x}</td>
                        </c:forEach>

                </tr>
                <tr class="value_row">
                    <td>${nodeRel.toNodeName}发送</td>
                    <c:forEach var="node" items="${nodeRel.recvFinalList}">
                        <td class="value_cell" value="${node}"><c:choose>
                                <c:when test="${empty node}">
                                    -
                                </c:when>
                                <c:otherwise>
                                    ${node}
                                </c:otherwise>
                            </c:choose></td>
                    </c:forEach>
                </tr>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>


    </c:forEach>
```

However, in my main page, the following function doesn't work because the dynamically created elements cannot be found!

```
function findMax() {
    $('tr').each(function(){
        //get the first value
        var max = $(this).find('td.value_cell').first().attr("value");
        if(isNaN(parseInt(max)))
            return;

        var highestElement = $(this).find('td.value_cell').first();
        $(this).find('td.value_cell').each(function(){
            var current = $(this).attr("value");

            if(!isNaN(parseInt(current))){
                if(current >= max) {
                    max = current;
                    highestElement = $(this);
                }
            }

        });

        if(max != 0)
            highestElement.css('background-color', 'red');
    });
}
```

What's wrong with my code?

**UPDATE:**

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33059192/jquery-find-dynamically-created-element-without-events) suggests that I can't select elements created in success call back function. Then is there any other way to find the max value in the dynamically created content and manipulate this content?

Comment: can you create a demo that shows the problem?

Comment: I guess this is the same problem as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33059192/jquery-find-dynamically-created-element-without-events). Take a look at the answer.

Comment: Does this answer mean that there is no way to access the elements created in the success call back? @Jakub Ječmínek

Comment: Try to move your findMax(); outside of success callback, and put it i done() callback (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and see how it behaves

Comment: can you please try with actual id('#table_body") instead of this in findMax method?

Comment: Still, the function cannot find the elements:( @andrew

Comment: Yes, I can get the element with the actual id inside the success callback! However, I really need to loop through all elements with a certain class. But the class selector doesn't work! why? @Jekin Kalariya

Comment: @deli. If you `concsole.log( $('tr').length )` in success or done callbacks, what do you get?

Comment: de li , can you please tell me how you test that class selector is not working?

Comment: I set a break point at the .each() function and when I step over, it skipped the whole function instead of going inside. @Jekin Kalariya